# Repeatable attribute tags in markojs

Tags: marko

I want a custom tag for tabs that will give me the possibility to write following code

```
app-tabset#my-tab
  @tab title="first"
    p -- content of first tab
  @tab title="second"
    p -- content of second tab
```

but I can't get it to consume repeated attribute, hence in `app-tabset.marko`

```
onMount() {
  console.log('incoming tabs', this.input.tab)
  // expected an array but only object of second tab
  //  "{title="second", renderBody: function}"
}
```

Reading the [docs in repeated attribute tags](https://markojs.com/docs/body-content/#repeated-attribute-tags) i add a `marko-tag.json`

```
{
  "<tab>": {
    "is-repeated": true
  }
}
```

This compiles fine but when loading the page i get

```
Render async fragment error (lasso-slot:head).
Exception: Error: Unable to load tag ([C:\projects\marko\src\components → C:\projects\marko\src\components\app-tabset\marko-tag.json]):
Error: Error while applying option of "<tab>".
Cause: Error: Unsupported properties of [is-repeated]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't found a solution yet, try this in your marko-tag.json file

```
{
    "@tabs <tab>[]": {
        "@title": "string"
    }
}
```